# How to append data to an output parameter which is an array?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, user-defined-types

I have a type like this ...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TYPE_X
 AS
  TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4000);
```

... which is used in a package:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE PACKAGE_TEST
 AS
 TYPE DETAILS
IS
 RECORD
   (
   EMPNO  NUMBER,
   ENAME  VARCHAR2(4000),
   DEPTNO NUMBER );
 TYPE DETAILS_ARRAY
 IS
 TABLE OF DETAILS;
 PROCEDURE PROC_TESTING_2(
   X TYPE_X,
   Y OUT DETAILS_ARRAY );
END;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY PACKAGE_TEST
AS
PROCEDURE PROC_TESTING_2(
  X TYPE_X,
  Y OUT DETAILS_ARRAY )
AS
BEGIN
FOR I IN 1..X.COUNT
LOOP
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(X(I));
  SELECT EMPNO,ENAME,DEPTNO INTO Y FROM EMP WHERE DEPTNO=X(I);
END LOOP;
END;
END;
```

I'd like to print the data into the record type by executing all the values from the TYPE_X list. The data needs to be appended till the loop exits. Appreciate your help. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

The approach which requires the least change to your existing code would be to populate a local variable of the record type, then append that to the OUT array.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY PACKAGE_TEST
AS
    PROCEDURE PROC_TESTING_2(
      X TYPE_X,
      Y OUT DETAILS_ARRAY )
    AS
        l_rec  DETAILS;
    BEGIN
        -- initialize output array
        y := package_test.details_array();
        FOR I IN 1..X.COUNT
        LOOP
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(X(I));
          SELECT EMPNO,ENAME,DEPTNO INTO lrec
          FROM EMP 
          WHERE DEPTNO=X(I);
          y.extend();
          y(y.count) := lrec;
        END LOOP;

    END;
END;
```

This would be inefficient for a large number of rows. In that case you should look to use BULK COLLECT instead:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY PACKAGE_TEST
AS
    PROCEDURE PROC_TESTING_2(
      X TYPE_X,
      Y OUT DETAILS_ARRAY )
    AS
        l_rec  DETAILS;
    BEGIN

        SELECT EMPNO,ENAME,DEPTNO 
        bulk collect INTO y
          FROM EMP 
          WHERE DEPTNO in ( select * from table (X));

    END;
END;
```

Comment: thank you! I was trying to join table(x) to the EMP. Not sure, but I went wrong somewhere, which lead to ask a question here. :)